# Need help with expectation of summation for power of Gaussian variable.

Tags: statistics, summation, expectation

I am trying to derive a formula, and getting stuck on a part of the derivation. Basically what I have is the following:

$$
P = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \mathbb{E} \Big[x^2[n] x^2[k] \Big]
$$

Here, each sample of $x[n]$ is $\sim  \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, and we can assume they are i.i.d.

I am confused as to how to proceed. I know that the cross terms are uncorrelated, so what I got is:

$$
P = (N^2 - N)\sigma^4 + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \mathbb{E} \Big[x^4[n]  \Big]
$$

But at this point I am not sure what else to do. Thank you.

Comment: Strange notation ...

Comment: @wolfies Strange notation where?

Comment: $x^2[n]$ .... (a) because your lower case $n$ can clash with upper  case $N$; (b) because something like $E[x_i^2 x_j^2]$ with $n$ rather than $N$ variables would be more standard, and (c) why sum from 0 to $n-1$, rather than 1 from $n$?

Comment: @wolfies Ah, I think this is a difference between fields. In engineering texts the usage of $n$ as an index for something of length $N$ is quite standard, same with the expectation. In fact $i$ and $j$ usage together is avoided because of clashing with imaginary values. (Comp sci uses $i$ whereas engineering uses $j$). :-)

Comment: In mathematical statistics, upper case letters are often reserved for random variables ... thus, your use of $N$ and $n$ together can be confusing. And I should have correctly written $E[X_i^2 X_j^2]$ above ... not $E[x_i^2 x_j^2]$.

Comment: @wolfies I think its clear from the context. Engineering uses statistics all the time and this is standard notation there. Eitherway, it is not a big deal.

Comment: The interesting part of your question ... you answered yourself! The only thing you are actually asking is: What is the 4th raw moment of a $N(0, \sigma^2)$ random variable ... and the latter is trivial -- just google it or wiki.

Comment: @wolfies Yeah, part of the problem was that I did not know that "raw moment" was called as such. I also forgot we could evaluate an expectation of a function of an rv as integral of the function with the rv's PDF. heropup helped me see this though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X \sim {\rm Normal}(0,\sigma^2)$.  Then one way to compute the fourth raw moment ${\rm E}[X^4]$ is to use the moment generating function:  recall that for a normal distribution, $$\begin{align*} M_X(t) &= {\rm E}[e^{tX}] = \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx \\ &= e^{(\sigma t)^2/2} \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(\sigma t)^2/2 + tx - x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx\\ &= e^{(\sigma t)^2/2} \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(x/\sigma - \sigma t)^2/2} \, dx \\ &= e^{(\sigma t)^2/2}, \end{align*}$$ the last equality due to the fact that the integrand is simply a normal density with mean $\sigma^2 t$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Subsequently, recall that the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moment is simply the $k^{\rm th}$ derivative of $M$ evaluated at $t = 0$:  $${\rm E}[X^k] = \frac{d^k}{dt^k}[M_X(t)]_{t=0}.$$  So we calculate the fourth derivative and get after some work $${\rm E}[X^4] = \left[\sigma^4 (3 + 6(\sigma t)^2 + (\sigma t)^4)e^{(\sigma t)^2/2} \right]_{t = 0} = 3\sigma^4.$$  Hence we obtain the result $$P = N(N+2)\sigma^4.$$

Comment: Thank you, but can you please expand on what the 't' is here? Where did the 't' come from? Also shouldnt the derivatives be using 'k' and not 'n'?

Comment: Yes, the derivative should have used $k$ instead of $n$--this has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks, can you please talk about the 't' here? I do not understand what this 't' is what is means. Thank you.

Comment: The MGF of a random variable is a function, for which $t$ is the independent variable.  It doesn't correspond to the support of the random variable or a probability--for the purposes of computing the moments, it is simply a "dummy" variable.  If you are not familiar with MGFs, then an alternative derivation involves the direct calculation of an integral of the form $\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^4 e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx$, which can be done via integration by parts with the initial choice $u = x^3$.

Comment: Thanks, it is a fantastic answer. Yes I am more familiar with the direct calculation you mentioned. In this case, the result of this direct calculation will be simply $\mathbb{E}[x^4]$ yes?

Comment: Yes.  However, it is a rather tedious computation:  $u = x^3$, $du = 3x^2 \, dx$, $dv = x e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx$, $v = -\sigma^2 e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$, and then we have to integrate by parts again, this time with the choice $u = x$.  Computing the MGF and its derivatives is more efficient in this case.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function for more information.

Comment: Interesting, thanks so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As the $X_i$ are non correlated,

- $E(X_i^2 X_j^2) = E(X_i^2) E(X_j^2)$ if $i \neq j$, and
- $E(X_i^2 X_j^2) = E(X_i^4) = E(X_j^4)$ if $i = j$.

As the $X_i$ are $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, the moments are [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) $E(X_i^2) = \sigma^2$, and $E(X^4) = 3 \sigma ^4$.

So $$P = \sum_0^{N-1} \sum_0^{N-1} E(X_i^2 X_j^2) = N(N-1) E(X_i^2) E(X_j^2) + 3N E(X_i^2) = N(N+2) \sigma^4.$$

Credits goes to @Spacey

Comment: Only the cross-terms can be factored like you have there. There are $N$ terms that are not cross terms, and thus we have to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[x^4]$

Comment: (Also I think you wanted to tag @heropup like so, this way you can get their attention and ask them).

Comment: @user1938185 Because for $i \neq j$, $E[X_i^2 X_j^2] = \sigma^4$, whereas for $i = j$, $E[X_i^2 X_j^2] = E[X_i^4] = 3\sigma^4$